# What to do in a (templated) stack pop method when the stack is empty?

Tags: c++, templates, error-handling, stack, api-design

I have written a templatized container class that takes type and template of template parameter.

```
template<class type, template<typename...> class Seq>
class stack1
{
private:
    int count;
    int size;
    Seq<type> st;
    //Seq<string> str;

public:
    stack1(size_t size):size(100), count(-1){ }
    void push(type elem);
    type pop();

};


template<class type, template<typename...> class Seq>
type stack1<type, Seq>::pop()
{
    if (count < 0)
    {
        cout << "stack1 is empty," << endl;
        /*How to handle this condition.*/

    }
    else
    {
        type elem; 
        elem = st.back();
        st.pop_back();
        count--;
        return elem;
    }
}
```

my question is , in the pop function how should I handle the error scenario when the container object is empty. I want to return some default value in that case,
e.g. 0/-1 if the container is int or ""/null if it is string or 0.0 in case it is float... something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@RSahu's suggestion is a fine thing to have.

An alternative could be changing the signature of the `pop()` function from:

```
type pop();
```

to

```
std::optional<type> pop();
```

and returning `std::nullopt` if the stack is empty, or a wrapped value in the usual case:

```
if (count < 0) {
    return std::nullopt;
}
```

Note that `std::optional` is introduced in the C++17 language standard; in C++14 you have it as `std::experimental::optional`, or you can use `boost::optional` for C++11 and earlier.

PS: It's a bad idea to have count be -1 when the element count is actually 0 - very confusing!

Comment: Yeah, I see it now and it looks exactly what I was looking for. -1 is just to show some error code and -1 was just a number. But in anycase I agree with you.

Answer (score 3):

One way to deal with it will be to throw an exception.

```
if (count < 0)
{
    throw std::out_of_range("stack1 is empty");
}
```

I would strongly discourage using `std::cout` to print a message to the terminal at that place. Use of `std::cout` in implementations of data structures is a poor programming practice.

Comment: I understand that cout is not at all the recommended thing but this is just a practice code. But I agree with you that exception could be the one way to go. but is there anything that we can handle using return codes or something.

Comment: @BhupeshPant, IMO, throwing an exception is the best solution. You allow the client code to use the class using normal function calls, keep your code robust, and allow the client code to deal with the exception the best way it can.